# Laravel Many-to-Many Relation

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a many-to-many relationship to establish that is not returning results, although there is relevant data.

*What am I missing?*

**MySQL Schema:**

```
entities
    - id

services
    - id

entity_service
    - entity_id
    - service_id
```

**Related Models:**

```
class Entity extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    // ...
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Service');
    }
}

class Service extends Eloquent
{
    // ...
    public function entities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Entity');
    }
}
```

**Controller / View**

```
$entity                         = Entity::findOrFail($id);
$locals['entity']               = $entity; // I can see all values available here
$locals['entity_services']      = $entity->services(); // I can't see any values here

@foreach ($entity_services as $service)
{{$service->id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: What happends if you use `$this->belongsToMany('Service','entity_service',' entity_id','service_id');`?

Comment: `Entity::findOrFail($id)` _does_ work, just to make sure?

Comment: Yes. I abbreviated the syntax in the example code. I will update it to let you see what I actually have. See the updated Controller / View section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that the `id` in the `services` table was an unique `VARCHAR` instead of the standard auto-incrementing `INT`. Fixing that and adding a `name` field cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel makes certain assumptions about your pivot table based on the model names.  It doesn't always get it right, and I suspect that's the case with "entities" and "entity_service."  Specify the pivot table and keys manually:

```
class Entity extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    // ...

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Service', 'entity_service', 'entity_id', 'service_id');
    }
}

class Service extends Eloquent
{
     // ...
    public function entities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Entity', 'entity_service', 'entity_id', 'service_id');
    }
}
```

Try eager loading the data:

```
Entity::with('services')->get();
```

The Laravel docs cover this in detail @ http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships.

Comment: I have implemented this approach, including eager loading, but get no response now. `$entity = Entity::with('services')->get();
        dd($entity);` outputs nothing.

Comment: Thought of something that may be relevant. The `$service->id` is not numeric. It is a `VARCHAR` since it is simply a unique list of values. Could that be why it is not working as expected?